# How to display a views block on pages with a specific combination of URL patterns?

Tags: views, 8, blocks, group

I'm using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module (1.0-alpha7) on a Drupal 8.1.5 and I want to display a view of recent article in my groups.

I want to display the view on groups page (`mywebsite/group/x` where x is id of group) but only this pattern of URL. For example when I create an article in a group the URL is : `mywebsite/group/x/node/create/article` and I don't want to show the view on this page.

I'm trying to use [Blocks Visibility Groups module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups) module to do it but for the moment I don't find the conditions to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups) module, perform these steps:

1. Define a new ***Block Visibility Group***, say you name it "***Group pages***".
2. For this newly created *Block Visibility Group" (named ***Group pages***"), add 2 ***conditions*** by selecting a condition related to the "Request path", which look like so:

   - Return true on the following pages: `group/*`.
   - **Do not** return true on the following pages: `group/*/node/create/article` (not sure if you want the `/article` suffix to be added, pick what fits your content types).
3. If you also want to show the `Global Blocks`, then mark the `Show Global Blocks` as checked.
4. Use the <kbd>Place block</kbd> button to place the Views block in the theme region of your choice.

**Notes**:

- if you're not familiar yet with this module, then have a look at the video about [Block Visibility Groups - Drupal 8 Blocks but Better](http://www.sixmiletech.com/content/block-visibility-groups-drupal-8-blocks-better).
- if this question was about D7, I'd use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module and specify similar Rules Conditions (based on the same current paths).
- don't get confused with all the ***Group***-stuff (the **[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)** module, versus the **[Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups)** module ...)

Comment: For the second condition, /group/*/* do the trick